# How to replace accented strings in attribute tables using Python or VBA ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.2, vb

I need to replace accented words, into the Field Calculator, to the same non-accented ones.

For example: María  ---> Maria

Need some help with this VB Code:

```
Dim data as integer
Dim contador
Dim words string

word= [POLYGON_Name] 

Dim v_matriz(5)
Dim n_matriz(5)

v_matriz(0) = "Á"
v_matriz(1) = "É"
v_matriz(2) = "Í"
v_matriz(3) = "Ó"
v_matriz(4) = "Ú"

n_matriz(0) = "A"
n_matriz(1) = "E"
n_matriz(2) = "I"
n_matriz(3) = "O"
n_matriz(4) = "U"

for each i in v_matriz
    data=InStr(word,v_matriz(contador))
    if dato>0 then
        word=Replace(word,v_matriz(contador),n_matriz(contador))
    end if
    contador=contador + 1
next
```

But I'm having problems, I'm new in this scripting style, and maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I could use Python also, if you want.

---

**SOLVED:**
This code in Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
import unicodedata
def strip_accents(s):
   return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
                  if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```

This in VALUE=

```
strip_accents(***your accented column***)
```

Thanks for all!

Comment: You need to use the unicode string instead. See my answer (to my own question) [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58251/how-to-replace-non-english-characters-in-attribute-tables-using-python).

Comment: You appear to be setting your v_matriz values and then overwriting them all, did you mean to use n_matriz for the second set?

Comment: @thehealingprocess sorry, copy&paste error. I'll try Martin´s suggestion.

Comment: @Martin sorry, but I'm too new in programming for taking your code into my code to fix it.  :(

Comment: That code is in Python, so it might not be applicable right away. The idea is that you find the unicode string (like `\xe4` for ä in that case) on, say, wikipedia. Then you replace your `"É"` with the unicode string. Keep in mind that they're case sensitive - you need two rows for each letter (i.e. `é` vs `É`). I'm not that familiar with VB, but maybe someone else can make pseudocode for you if you need.