# Using unicode characters (arabic) in Select By Attribute of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, internationalization, arabic

I'm new to Python scripting with ArcGIS for Desktop and I have unicode characters (arabic) in my attribute table.

I want to use these characters in my script but when I try to do that the script does not work.

How can I use unicode characters in my script?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/test"
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
listlyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"","")
# hatta agar chand dataframe ham dashte bashim baz ham select ra anjam mdahad
for a in listlyr:
    delim = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(a,"City")

    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (a, "NEW_SELECTION", delim+"='u'\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xb4\xd9\x87\xd8\xb1''")
```

**u'\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xb4\xd9\x87\xd8\xb1'** means 'نوشهر'

Comment: Try using the corresponding unicode string in the script instead, something like `u'\xe4`.

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58251/how-to-replace-non-english-characters-in-attribute-tables-using-python/58300#58300) to get an idea how to start.

Comment: I couldn't solve my problem . i used unicode syntax lie u'\...' but it dosn't work.

Comment: Could you update your question with your current code?

Comment: I updated my question .please help me . thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your u'\xd9\x86\xd9\x88\xd8\xb4\xd9\x87\xd8\xb1' is utf-8.

instead use unicode. Also wrap the value with single quote.

```
u"City = '\u0646\u0648\u0634\u0647\u0631'"
```

and don't bother with delim. Should work without (if you're on recent (like 10.2 ish) release).

.

to understand unicode

watch [Ned Batchelder's "Pragmatic Unicode, or, How do I stop the pain"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc)

read  [Python docs on unicode](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)