# Using “calculate field” in python script fails to display Arabic characters correctly

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, internationalization, unicode, arabic

Using “calculate field” in python script fails to display Arabic characters correctly.

I have exported the modelbuilder to python script, but unfortunately the Arabic characters cannot by displayed correctly when the script is executed.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
# Set Geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "D:\\Test.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\\Test.gdb"
# Local variables:
Buildings_POINTS = "D:\\U.gdb\\Buildings_POINTS"
# Process: Calculate Field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Buildings_POINTS, "Ref_MOLG", "\"المخططات الهيكلياهلين المعلن للاعتراض\"", "PYTHON", "")
```

Now when I copy the script to python:
[image]
[image]

I believe that its a Unicode issue. how can I fix it.

Comment: Perhaps look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89162/using-unicode-characters-arabic-in-select-by-attribute-of-arcgis-for-desktop

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change python encoding, you may look at link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996475/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-web-page-containing-mostly-arabic-tex

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728891/correct-way-to-define-python-source-code-encoding

Comment: Hi Ncelick and PolyGeo, There the problem still there.