# Cause of Field Calculator UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, error-000539, unicodeencodeerror

```
def Befahrung(value1,value2):
  if value1 is ' ':
    return ' '
  else: 
return "G:\\Example\\" + str(value1) + "\\File_" + str(value2) + ".pdf"
```

I try to create a field with a hyperlink. It works very well until i hit a special charakter. What do i have to change?

This is the error:

> ERROR 000539: Error running expression: Befahrung(u" ",u"Mönch")
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "", line 5, in Befahrung
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in
>   position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: This question is more for stackoverflow

Comment: Does this code work when you run it from an IDE like IDLE?  If it does, then it may point to a Field Calculator issue, but, if not, then I think it is better researched/asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Error in IDLE, too. I will try it in stackoverflow.
ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<expression>, line 1)

Comment: When you use a different argument for value2 using plain text (such as "test"), do you still get the issue?

Comment: The asker has posted to Stack Overflow now so to see the outcome click http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445982/syntax-error-in-arcgis-field-calculator

Comment: As an extra clarification would you be able to edit your question to include the precise code that you ran in IDLE to see the error, please?

Comment: There is another Q&A here that may help (I suspect that it may be a duplicate): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58251/how-to-replace-non-english-characters-in-attribute-tables-using-python