# replace ü/ ö/ ä / spaces and brackets in Attribute Table

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update

I've got a Polygon Feature Class of communities in switzerland. Unfortunately, the names in the attribute Field "NAME" include spaces, brackets and ä/ ö/ ü characters. For further processing, i need to remove the spaces and brackets and to replace ä --> ae, ö --> oe, ü --> ue.
I've tried to do this using update cursor but i don't get it to work:

`with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("AVR_GEM","NAME") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row = str(row).replace("ä","ae")
        row = str(row).replace("ö","oe")
        row = str(row).replace("ü","oe")
        row = str(row).replace(" ","")
        row = str(row).replace("(","")
        cursor.updateRow(row)`

Can anyone show me a quick way to get the job done?

Comment: Could you tell us where it is failing? What error messages do you see? I presume this is ArcGIS, what version are you using?

Comment: Think of row as a list and name is the second item you want to edit.  So you need to choose that and you normally do that by the index. In your case it would be row[1] = str(row[1]).replace..... Your updateRow line stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("AVR_GEM","NAME"):
for row in cursor:
    row[0] = str(row[0]).replace("ä","ae").replace("ö","oe").replace("ü","oe").replace(" ","").replace("(","")
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Alternativly you may also directly change the row´s attribute:

```
row.NAME = ...
```

Comment: when i apply this, i get the following message:  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128).Obviously the "ü" i'm specifying to be replaced cannot be dealt with...

Comment: This doesn't work since you need to use unicode strings instead of the actual ä and ö. See this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58251/how-to-replace-non-english-characters-in-attribute-tables-using-python